# iBeacon UUID not showing correctly Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, ibeacon

I am trying to display the iBeacon UUID when an application scans. I am able to display the Minor, Major, rssi, etc but I am unable to display the uuid values. Printing the values for uuid results in blank/no values even when values for minor, major appear. I have tried multiple ways but nothing seems to work. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated:

BeaconParser.kt

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
import android.util.Log
import com.smartahc.android.example.ibeacon.ibeacon.bean.Beacon
import java.util.*
import kotlin.experimental.and

class BeaconParser {

    companion object {

        val TAG: String = "beacon"

        fun parse(device: BluetoothDevice?, rssi: Int, data: ByteArray): Beacon {
            val beacon = Beacon()
            beacon.rssi = rssi
            device.let {
                it?.name?.let {
                    beacon.name = it
                }
                it?.address?.let {
                    beacon.mac = it
                }
            }
            // parse data
            if (data.isNotEmpty()) {
                return parseData(beacon, data)
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "data >> is null")
            }
            return beacon
        }

        private fun parseData(beacon: Beacon, scanData: ByteArray): Beacon {
            Log.e("beacon", "name >> ${beacon.name}")
            var startByte = 2
            while (startByte <= 5) {
                if (scanData[startByte + 2].toInt() and 0xff == 0x02 && scanData[startByte + 3].toInt() and 0xff == 0x15) {
                    val major = (scanData[startByte + 20] and 0xff.toByte()) * 0x100 + (scanData[startByte + 21] and 0xff.toByte())
                    beacon.major = major
                    val minor = (scanData[startByte + 22] and 0xff.toByte()) * 0x100 + (scanData[startByte + 23] and 0xff.toByte())
                    beacon.minor = minor
                    beacon.txPower = scanData[startByte + 24].toInt()
                    break
                }
                startByte++
            }
            val uuidBytes = ByteArray(16)
            System.arraycopy(scanData, startByte + 4, uuidBytes, 0, 16)
            beacon.uuid = parseUUID(uuidBytes)
            Log.v("beaconuuidzzz", "result > ${beacon.uuid}")

            return beacon
        }
        private fun parseUUID(uuidBytes: ByteArray): String {
            val hexString = bytesToHexString(uuidBytes)
            Log.v(TAG, hexString)
            val sb = StringBuilder()
            if (hexString.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                hexString?.let {
                    sb.append(it.substring(0, 8))
                    sb.append("-")
                    sb.append(it.substring(8, 12))
                    sb.append("-")
                    sb.append(it.substring(12, 16))
                    sb.append("-")
                    sb.append(it.substring(16, 20))
                    sb.append("-")
                    sb.append(it.substring(20, 32))
                }

                Log.v(TAG, sb.toString())
            }
            return sb.toString()

        }

        private fun bytesToHexString(src: ByteArray?): String? {
            val stringBuilder = StringBuilder("")
            if (src == null || src.isEmpty()) {
                return stringBuilder.toString()
            }
            Log.v("byte >> ", Arrays.toString(src))
            for (aSrc in src) {
                val v: Int = (aSrc and 0xFF.toByte()).toInt()
                val hv = Integer.toHexString(v)
                if (hv.length < 2) {
                    stringBuilder.append(0)
                }
                stringBuilder.append(hv)
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add Log.d lines to your parseUUID method, then run the code to explore which lines are getting executed and which are not.  You can then print out intermediate values in these debug lines to explore why.  This is the basic process of debugging.  You can also use breakpoints to step through your code to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: I tried that but it just seems like there's no data coming in for UUID. Do you see any problems with the code for parsing/obtaining the uuid?

Comment: I think I got it to work-thanks for the help